# Adding lon/lat grid on map in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules, qgis-print-layouts

I am working through this tutorial that I think was intended for 2.8x -  https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html

Step 24 advises on how to add a grid on a map in Layout view. But there is no longer a CRS menu in Item Properties. In the tutorial, the grid appears when the coordinate reference system is set to WGS84 in the CRS Selector dialog box. Then the interval is set a 5 degrees. I have set the CRS to WGS84, but has not appeared on the map, and I don't see how to set the grid interval to 5 degrees.

How do I do this in version 3.0?

Here is the map with the version 3.0 Item Properties:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to scroll down just a little bit more to find **Grids** options.

[image]

Then the difference from the linked tutorial are:

- Click on <kbd>Modify grid...</kbd> to call up `Appearance` properties.
- Set CRS for the Grid in this `Appearance` menu.