# Adding local LonLat to coordinate grid using QGIS

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

How can I add my areas lon and lat to coordinate grid on QGIS3?

For example, my map's horizontal coordinate grid contain 55.4E, 55.6E, ... and vertical coordinate grid contain 29.2 N, 29.7N,..). I'm trying but see incorrect decimal values.

Comment: I think you should explain a little bit more precise what exactly you want: A grid-layer (map view window), adding a grid to a print layout, or ....?  And also shortly describe what you "tried" in order to give people an impression about your task specific knowledge. So you will also avoid to get answers to aspects you already know.

Comment: So, if you mean the print layout this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277840/adding-lon-lat-grid-on-map-in-qgis-3-0?rq=1) may help you.

Comment: I want to make a map for my study area including north arrow, scale bar and exact coordinate in Lon and Lat (exact coordinate of my study area for instance 55E , 55.4E on x axis and 29N,29.6N on y axis) around this map. But I can not do it.. I just see irrelevant utm x and y on my coordinate grid around the map!

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works